# Google Analytics tracking code not working

Tags: html

I have checked all the help guides and troubleshooting articles I can find that are supplied by Google. I have also read two articles on how to install the code and even watched a Youtube video that uses the UA snippet. However, with multiple different reformatting and untouched efforts I can not get Google Analytics to be able to pick-up on the code.

Here is my head code, which should work unless I'm stupid:

```
    <head>

    <title>Pheta Online | Home</title>

    <meta name="author" content="NSquared">
    <meta name="description" content="Pheta's Personal Website">



<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="Res/0_Stylesheets/ARCH.css">

<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-45791280-1', 'phetaonline.co.uk');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
    </head>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried copying your entire script to the bottom of the your web page?

In the past, I've copied my Google Analytics code to be placed at the bottom of the web page. (before the ending body and html tags); however I understand that Google Webmaster Tools now require you place it in between the head tags. [Google WebMaster Tools](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1008080?rd=1).

You could also check their troubleshooting page as well.

But I read in this article ([Where should the Google Analytics Code be Placed?](http://www.lunametrics.com/blog/2012/02/09/where-put-google-tracking-code/#sr=g&m=o&cp=or&ct=-tmc&st=%28opu%20qspwjefe%29&ts=1384670787)) that it could be placed anywhere.

Please let me know and hope this helps!

Comment: Seems like Google took a long time to register the code. It works without any changes. Thank you for your help. :D